# NSArray valueForKey:@"@max.self"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, key-value-coding

I have an `Array` of numbers in which I want to find the highest value.
I am doing this as follows:

```
NSNumber *test = [fuelConsumption valueForKey:@"@max.self"];
```

When I Build then Run, I am presented with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSArrayM 0x7b26e8d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key max.self.'

From what I understand, this is how one looks for this value.
Any ideas where this may be going wrong?

I am programming for iOS9.x and using Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because, when you give `valueForKey:` an `NSString`, it will invoke `objectForKey:` and when string starts with an `@` it invokes `[super valueForKey:]`, which may call `valueForUndefinedKey:` which may raise an exception.

So, change `valueForKey:` to `valueForKeyPath:` like,

```
NSNumber *test = [fuelConsumption valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

Read more about [kvc-collection-operators](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `valueForKeyPath` for that

```
 NSNumber *test = [fuelConsumption valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

For more about `Collection Operators` read apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html).